# Groovy : Cannot set a request body for a DELETE/GET method

Tags: groovy

When i am executing this via curl its working :

```
 curl -u -X DELETE -H 'accept:application/json' http://localhost:13000/test/test_userid"
```

I made a common function which accept methodtype ( GET, POST, DELETE etc) and content type( JASON, TEXT ) for the httpbuilder.

```
 def public httpRequest(String url, String content, Method requestType, ContentType contentType)
 {
        try{
            def myClient = new HTTPBuilder(url)
            myClient.request(requestType,contentType) { req ->         
            headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
            body=content
            response.success = { resp, data ->           
                def reponse=[resp:resp,data:data]
                return reponse
            }

            response.failure = { resp ->
                println 'Response Code '+resp.statusLine
            }
            // called only for a 404 (not found) status code:
            response.'404' = { resp ->
                println 'Not found'
             }
            }
        }
      catch(Exception e)
       {
           println "error"+e.getProperties()
       }
}
```

Now if i make a POST request , its working. 
However if i make a GET or DELETE request using

```
 def response = httpRequest(url,"",DELETE,JSON)
```

or

```
 def response = httpRequest(url,"",GET,TEXT)
```

its shows the following error :-

```
 error[message:Cannot set a request body for a DELETE/GET method, class:class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Do i need to make a separate function for GET/DELETE?
because

```
 myClient.request(requestType) { req ->         
            headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
            body=content
            response.success = { resp, data ->           
                def reponse=[resp:resp,data:data]
                return reponse
            }

            response.failure = { resp ->
                println 'Response Code '+resp.statusLine
            }
            // called only for a 404 (not found) status code:
            response.'404' = { resp ->
                println 'Not found'
             }
            }
        }
```

WORKS

Comment: I don't believe GET requests should have a body http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: yeah it seems i have to make a separate function then. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete and Get wont accept Body , hence the solution is to make a check and execute accordingly

```
 if(requestType.equals(DELETE)||requestType.equals(GET))
       {
           try{
               def myClient = new HTTPBuilder(url)
               myClient.request(requestType) { req ->          
               headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
               headers.Accept = 'application/json'
               response.success = { resp, data ->          
                    def reponse=[resp:resp,data:data]
                    return reponse
               }

               response.failure = { resp ->
                   println 'Response Code '+resp.statusLine
               }
               // called only for a 404 (not found) status code:
               response.'404' = { resp ->
                   println 'Not found'
                }
               }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
              println "error"+e.getProperties()
           }
       }
    else
     <---post request -->
```